# How do I remove "\U0000fffc" from a string in Swift?

Tags: string, swift

I have added an image to a textfield, and wish to remove it again. I've tried the following two lines to no avail?

```
string = string.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\U0000fffc", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
string = string.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\U0000fffc", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks so much!

Comment: Are you trying to replace the literal sequence "\U0000fffc`, or the Unicode character U+FFFC ? Some more context would be helpful.

Comment: I'm guessing the Unicode character? I added an image to a textfield, and wish to remove it again.

Comment: Please show the result of `println(string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding)!)` so that we can see what the string actually contains.

Comment: `<00000048 00000065 0000006c 0000006c 0000006f 0000000a 0000000a 0000fffc>` from "Hello\n\n\U0000fffc"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unicode escape sequences are differently in Swift from those in Objective-C, the Unicode character `U+FFFC` is escaped as `\u{fffc}`:

This is your string:

```
var string = "Hello\n\n\u{fffc}"
println(string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding)!)
// <00000048 00000065 0000006c 0000006c 0000006f 0000000a 0000000a 0000fffc>
```

Now remove all `U+FFFC` characters:

```
string = string.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\u{fffc}", withString: "")
println(string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding)!)
// <00000048 00000065 0000006c 0000006c 0000006f 0000000a 0000000a>
```

Note that `options:` and `range:` are optional parameters and not
needed in this case.

---

**Update for Swift 3/4:**

```
var string = "Hello\n\n\u{fffc}"
print(string.data(using: .utf32BigEndian)! as NSData)
// <00000048 00000065 0000006c 0000006c 0000006f 0000000a 0000000a 0000fffc>
```

```
string = string.replacingOccurrences(of: "\u{fffc}", with: "")
print(string.data(using: .utf32BigEndian)! as NSData)
// <00000048 00000065 0000006c 0000006c 0000006f 0000000a 0000000a>
```

Comment: Btw, U+FFFC  is the "OBJECT REPLACEMENT CHARACTER" so I wonder how that got into the string ...

Comment: an NSTextAttachment in NSAttributedString will be converted to "\u{FFFC}" in its `string` property for placeholder

Answer (score 2):

The method `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` can work on parts of the string or the whole string.

For example, this works on the entire string, by giving it the range from start of the string to the end:

```
let original = "First part \\U0000fffc Last part"

let originalRange = Range<String.Index>(start: original.startIndex, end: original.endIndex)

let target = original.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\U0000fffc", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: originalRange)

println(target) // prints "First part  Last part"
```

Comment: "\U0000fffc" was added to the string because of inserting an image, does this change how it can be removed?

Comment: Basically, I added an image to a textfield, and wish to remove it again.

Comment: `range: nil`  does a search/replace on the *entire* string, so that is not the problem.

Comment: Answer updated, thank you for the precision Martin, I was completely wrong about the reason why it failed for Randal.

Comment: @ericd: Your help is appreciated in spite of the lack of information I gave :)