# Remove U\0000fffc unicode scalar from string

Tags: ios, swift, string, unicode, nsattributedstring

I receive an `NSAttributedString` that contains a `NSTextAttachment`. I want to remove that attachment, and it looks like it is represented as `"\u{ef}"` in the string. Printing the unicode scalars of such string, it also seems that unicode scalar for the `"\u{ef}"` is `U\0000fffc`.

I tried to do this:

```
noAttachmentsText = text.replacingOccurrences(of: "\u{ef}", with: "")
```

with no success, so I'm trying by comparing unicode scalars:

```
var scalars = Array(text.unicodeScalars)
for scalar in scalars {
   // compare `scalar` to `U\0000fffc`
}
```

but I'm not able either to succeed in the comparison.
How could I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove "\U0000fffc" from a string in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973684/how-do-i-remove-u0000fffc-from-a-string-in-swift)

Comment: @MikeAlter that is not working for me

Comment: @AppsDev did you got its answer?

Answer (score 0):

But this code works for me   from    [How do I remove "\U0000fffc" from a string in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973684/how-do-i-remove-u0000fffc-from-a-string-in-swift)

```
    let original = "First part \u{ef} Last part"
    let originalRange = Range<String.Index>(start: original.startIndex, end: original.endIndex)
    let target = original.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\u{ef}", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: originalRange)

    print(target)
```

Output :

"First part ï Last part"

to

First part  Last part

Comment: Thanks. Is that `swift 3`? Range initialization does not seem to work

Answer (score 0):

U can use similar code for **swift 3** just replace unicode using **replacingOccurrences** option for exapmle :

```
func stringTocleanup(str: String) -> String {
        var result = str
        result = result.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "\"")
            .replacingOccurrences(of: "\u{10}", with: "")
        return result
}
```